# A content rotator that moves vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotator

Does anyone out there have a good example of a vertical content rotator in jQuery or Javascript? Especially ones with navigation arrows and thumbnails?

Most that I've seen are horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) will do this for you. [Here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html)'s an example showing the vertical functionality (with arrows).

Answer (score 0):

I'll make a suggestion for you.  Create a div with a defined height and overflow set to hidden.  Create another div inside the defined height div and place your content with it. Using the animate function of jquery, animate the child div upwards with marginTop or top with relative positioning.  Use some creativity to make it pretty or dynamically load content.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a script i'll make one for you. But you can just get any horizontal carusel and change the left/right attributes with top/bottom (the ones in animation). Also jCarousel is a good example. (the one Andrew suggested).